# I can't debug my program in intellij idea CE

Tags: scala

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:39989', transport: 'socket' on intellij idea CE. I can't debug my program. Any suggestions?

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:39989', transport: 'socket'
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/12/29 17:29:47 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.2
17/12/29 17:29:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/12/29 17:29:49 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ashfaq-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
17/12/29 17:29:49 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/12/29 17:29:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ashfaq
17/12/29 17:29:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ashfaq
17/12/29 17:29:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/12/29 17:29:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/12/29 17:29:49 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ashfaq); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ashfaq); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 46133.
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b3b48105-28be-4781-a395-c7e83cc72e8c
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 393.1 MB
17/12/29 17:29:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/12/29 17:29:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/12/29 17:29:53 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
17/12/29 17:29:53 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 33583.
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:33583
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33583, None)
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:33583 with 393.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33583, None)
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33583, None)
17/12/29 17:29:54 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33583, None)
17/12/29 17:29:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 236.5 KB, free 392.8 MB)
17/12/29 17:29:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 22.9 KB, free 392.8 MB)
17/12/29 17:29:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.2.15:33583 (size: 22.9 KB, free: 393.1 MB)
17/12/29 17:29:59 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at scalaApp.scala:13
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/ashfaq/Desktop/saclaAPP/data/UserPurchaseHistory.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1968)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
    at ScalaApp$.main(scalaApp.scala:18)
    at ScalaApp.main(scalaApp.scala)
17/12/29 17:29:59 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/12/29 17:29:59 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
17/12/29 17:29:59 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 10.0.2.15:33583 in memory (size: 22.9 KB, free: 393.1 MB)
17/12/29 17:29:59 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:39989', transport: 'socket'
17/12/29 17:30:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-58667739-7c15-4665-8ede-fde9c3ff1d83

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: check if your VM has an IP and if it is the good one. if no, turn off and turn on (not a restart, you need to shutdown the machine)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you are trying to open a file which doesn't exist. The fisrt line of the error message says so:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/ashfaq/Desktop/saclaAPP/data/UserPurchaseHistory.csv
```